# Date substitution markers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pymssql

I am facing an issue in processing the raw input datetime ('06/17/2023, 02:41:38') from tuple into SQL Server table which is define as datetime.

My SQL:

```
     my_sql = insert into @my_table
        (
            ename
            , eid
            , eloc
            , ejoindate

        )
        values (%s,%s,%s,%s)

cursor.execute(my_sql, ('ram', 'ABC001', 'India', '06/17/2023, 02:41:38')
```

On successful run, the col `ejoindate` should have the value like this `'2023-06-17 02:41:38.000'`

getting the error

> (242, b'The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')

Any suggestions to deal with datetime conversion or something?

Comment: Try to pass the datetime values using an unambiguous format: `'2023-06-17T02:41:38'`.

Comment: I can not change the input as it comes from other application to GCS bucket. 
It is something to be managed in sql query.

Comment: You have a python code, I'm quite sure you can convert and format dates there

Comment: If only pymsswl supported "parameters" other than strings...

Comment: Hi @ThomA, can you please provide an example? Thanks

Comment: Of what, @rajS..?

Comment: how to deal with parameters?

Comment: You *are* using parameters. The problem is your value, `06/17/2023, 02:41:38` isn't a valid string that can be implicitly converted. You need to make it an ambiguous format, such as the format @Zhorov suggested earlier. `20230617 02:41:38` would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still need one more point or I would have used a comment.

Take out the comma between the data and time and it should work provided the computer is set for US date format.

```
cursor.execute(my_sql, ('ram', 'ABC001', 'India', '06/17/2023, 02:41:38')
```

Maybe something like this?

```
values (%s,%s,%s, REPLACE(%s, ',', ''))
```

Comment: This may well still fail; for most of the world there aren't 17 months in a year (just 12).